# Write code to determine the total cost of a flight

Tags: java

The total cost can be calculated by adding the cost of departingFlight and returningflight. However, departingFlight and returningFlight are both objects from the class Flight. Is there a way to add these to values to get the total cost?

This is what I tried:

```
public Double getTotalCost() {
    return departingFlight + returningFlight;
}//End of method
```

Flight class:
public class Flight {

```
private String code;
private String origin;
private String destination;
private String departureTime;
private String arrivalTime;
private Double cost;

public Flight(String cde, String orig , String dest, String dtime,String atime,Double cst) {
    code = cde;
    origin = orig;
    destination = dest;
    departureTime = dtime;
    arrivalTime = atime;
    cost = cst;

}//End of constructor flight

public String getCode() {
    return code;

}//End of method

public String getDepartureTime() {
    return departureTime;
}//End of method

public Double getCost() {
    return cost;
}//End of method

public String toString() {
    return "" + cost + "\t " + origin + " " + departureTime + "\t" + destination + " " + arrivalTime; 
    }//end of toString method
```

}//End of class

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: can you share the Flight class?

Comment: Sure thing @Erwin

Comment: just do departingFlight.getCost() + returningFlight.getCost() then

Answer (score 1):

this is what you need to do. add two flights to arguments and then :

```
public Double getTotalCost(Flight a,Flight b) {
    return a.getCost() + b.getCost();
}//End of method
```